# How can I create a RuleSet with a .NET FluentValidation InlineValidator?

Tags: c#, .net, action, fluentvalidation

I'm creating an `InlineValidator` (from the FluentValidation nuget package/library).

```
var validator = new InlineValidator<Person>;
validator.RuleFor(x => x.Surname).NotNull();
validator.RuleSet("someRuleSet", () => {
    // ?????
            });
```

When I try to call the RuleSet method in there, it seems to not compile.

How can I create a RuleSet against an `InlineValidator` please ?

Here's the example ruleset i'm trying...

```
.RuleSet("someRuleSet", () =>
{
    RuleFor(x => x.Name).NotNull();
    RuleFor(x => x.Age).NotEqual(0);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't access `RuleFor` as a global method, it sits on the `InlineValidator`. Here's an example of how you can add a `RuleSet` and then validate against it:

```
// Setup the inline validator and ruleset
var validator = new InlineValidator<Person>();

validator.RuleSet("test", () =>
{
    validator.RuleFor(x => x.Name).NotNull();
    validator.RuleFor(x => x.Age).NotEqual(0);
});

var person = new Person();

// Validate against the RuleSet specified above
var validationResult = validator.Validate(person, ruleSet: "test");    

Console.WriteLine(validationResult .IsValid); // Prints False
```